# How to avoid the BSOD after dumping a system image onto a new computer

Tags: windows-xp, images, bsod, hal

We prepare lots of computers, which only have in common using Windows XP, having an Intel CPU and being at least Pentium 4, with a long and tedious software configuration.

It's so long, and involves so boring work, that we are just dumping an image from a pre configured machine into every PC, accepting that it will crash on 99% of first boots, and then doing a repair install and fixing whatever is missing after.

Is there anyway we can work around this blue screen and boot that system without having to do a repair install? Is it possible to disable HAL for a boot? Or at least make it detect again the hardware?

Comment: The boring process is the same as in this [old question](http://superuser.com/questions/337160/automate-configuration-of-windows-computers-without-disk-imaging), but the computers are for a different usage, that's why we can use imaging with them.

Comment: If you did a sysprep before boot, then it will detect the hardware again.  And no, you can't disable HAL.  Unless you enjoy updating and buying 100 versions of your programs based on each and every motherboard and CPU combination.

Comment: Uh, is there some reason you can't just use sysprep?

Comment: I've read about Sysprep but seemed too much work, I'll try it asap anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enter Easy Sysprep in Google.